# Remove Backslashes from Data with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Disclaimer: I have about 3 months of programming experience ... so apologies in advance for any stupid questions.

I have a 9GB CSV file I'm trying to clean up using Python 2.7

I need to remove/replace/strip whatever you want to call it .... all instances of "\" scattered throughout the data.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
#Python 2.7
csvfileIn = open("dataexample.csv", "r")
csvOut = open("dataexample2.csv", "w")
for i, row in enumerate(csvfileIn.readline()):
    row = row.replace("\"", "")
    csvOut.write(row)
csvOut.close()
```

This does not iterate through the CSV file as I hoped it would.
I was given the advice to use readline() as opposed to readlines() because the file is so large.

I would attach the example data file, but I don't have enough street cred to attach a file. I guess the last question I posted was stupid, so I lost some rep points.
[screenshot of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLvA.jpg)

Thank you for any help!

*Updated/Fixed Code*

```
#Python 2.7
csvfileIn = open("dataexample.csv", "r")
csvOut = open("dataexample2.csv", "w")


for i, row in enumerate(csvfileIn):
    row = row.replace("\\", "")
    csvOut.write(row)


csvOut.close()
csvfileIn.close()
```

Comment: `enumerate(csvfileIn.readline())` will only enumerate the first line of the file. Files are iterable, so just use `enumerate(csvfileIn)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)
replace     `row = row.replace("\"", "")`
with     `row = row.replace("\\", "")`

You should escape the backslash

2) As suggested by [Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) in the comment,  replace `enumerate(csvfileIn.readline())` with `enumerate(csvfileIn)`

Alternatively, if `i` has never been used in your code,  just iterate the file by `for row in csvfileIn:`

Finally, don't forget to close `csvfileIn`

Comment: I'm getting an "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'"? I updated my original question with the code I tried and error message.

Comment: @Tommy  if you use enumerate.  it is `for i, row in enumerate(csvfileIn)` then row is string other than tuple

Comment: @Tommy replace `for row in enumerate(csvfileIn):` with `for i, row in enumerate(csvfileIn):
`

Comment: Thank you @Haifeng Zhang and @Rawing!!!! I misunderstood your explanation and took "i" out. Sorry about that!!! Thank you so much for helping me out. Script is working like a champ now!!!!!

Comment: @Tommy glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Use double backslash

```
row.replace("\\", "")
```

`\\` double backslash means backslash in string

Single backslash preceding char means special character ex: \n - new line